# How to solve two equations numerical by Python?

Tags: python, numerical, sympy

Maybe it´s the easiest way to show you the code and try to explain it later:

```
sigma_aussen = 7.1
roh_aussen = 38
lambda_schreib = 532*10**-9
lambda_rek = 432*10**-9
sigma_aussen=radians(sigma_aussen)
roh_aussen=radians(roh_aussen)

def BraggMatch(sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_rek):


    gw2, sig_innen, ref_innen, sig_din, ref_din, p2, sig, ref =var('gw2 sig_innen ref_innen sig_din ref_din p2 sig ref')

    sigma = asin(1/n_brech*sin(sigma_aussen))
    roh = asin(1/n_brech*sin(roh_aussen))
    gw = (sigma+roh)/2
    sigma_din =  (roh-sigma)/2
    roh_din =  (sigma-roh)/2


    gw2 = (asin(1/n_brech*sin(sig))+asin(1/n_brech*sin(ref))/2)
    print("gw2: ", gw2)

    sig_innen = asin(1/n_brech*sin(sig))
    ref_innen = asin(1/n_brech*sin(ref))
    print ("sig_innen: ", sig_innen)
    print ("ref_innen: ", ref_innen)


    sig_din = gw2-sig_innen
    ref_din = gw2-ref_innen
    print ("ref_din: ", ref_din)

    p = lambda_schreib/(n_brech*(sin(sigma_din)-sin(roh_din)))
    print ("p: ",p)
    p2 = lambda_rek/n_brech*(sin(sig_din)-sin(ref_din))
    print ("p2: ", p2)

    Winkel=nsolve([gw-gw2, p-p2],[sig,ref], [0,0])
    return Winkel    

Winkel = BraggMatch(sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_rek)
```

Here my explanation: BraggMatch ist a method which returns two angles in radians.

the two equations are gw-gw2=0 and p-p2=0. gw and p are two known variables. only two variables are unknown, sig and ref. that two unknown variables should be solved nummerical and get returned in the method BraggMatch.

With the software Maple solving that two equations is no problem. Maybe it could help, showing you the solution: sig=0.064 and ref=0.734

This is the error: "ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (0.0448851 > 2.1684e-19)
Try another starting point or tweak arguments."

You make me very thankful by helping me solving this problem. It is the core of my master thesis.

---

First, thanks for your fast reaktion.

But I don´t think that this is the right way. You´re right, i´ve forgot the `n_brech=1.5`.
Today, i find out, that `gw-gw2` can solve analytical. So i only need a solution for `p-p2`.
The solutions of `ref`and `sig`are can be between PI and -PI, by a variation of `sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, lambda_rek`, that´s the reason i´m start looking a solution at 0.

Here you see my new code:

```
n_brech = 1.5
sigma_aussen = 7.1
roh_aussnen = 38
lambda_schreib = 532*10**-9
lambda_rek = 432*10**-9
sigma_aussen=radians(sigma_aussen)
roh_aussen=radians(roh_aussen)

def BraggMatch(sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_rek):

    gw2, sig_innen, ref_innen, sig_din, ref_din, p2, sig, ref =var('gw2 sig_innen ref_innen sig_din ref_din p2 sig ref')

    sigma = asin(1/n_brech*sin(sigma_aussen))
    roh = asin(1/n_brech*sin(roh_aussen))
    gw = (sigma+roh)/2
    sigma_din =  (roh-sigma)/2
    roh_din =  (sigma-roh)/2


    gw2 = (asin(1/n_brech*sin(sig))+asin(1/n_brech*sin(ref))/2)
    ref_list=solve(gw-gw2,ref)
    ref=ref_list[0]
    print("ref: ", ref)
    gw2 = (asin(1/n_brech*sin(sig))+asin(1/n_brech*sin(ref))/2)

    sig_innen = asin(1/n_brech*sin(sig))
    ref_innen = asin(1/n_brech*sin(ref))
    sig_din = gw2-sig_innen
    ref_din = gw2-ref_innen

    p = lambda_schreib/(n_brech*(sin(sigma_din)-sin(roh_din)))
    p2 = lambda_rek/(n_brech*(sin(sig_din)-sin(ref_din)))
    print ("p2: ", p2)
    print ("p-p2: ", p-p2)
    sig=fsolve(p-p2,0)
    Winkel=[sig, ref]
    return Winkel

Winkel=BraggMatch(sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_rek)
```

If you are good at Maple, in the image i upload, you see totaly the problem i have to solve in Python, because here i can visualize it with VPython. The Maple code returns the angles in degrees, which is no problem.
[image]

---

Now I tried to write the code, like I did in Maple. I get some now Error:

`ZeroDivisionError`

Here is the code:

```
n_brech = 1.5
sigma_aussen = 7.1
roh_aussen = 38
lambda_schreib = 532*10**-9
lambda_rek = 432*10**-9
sigma_aussen=radians(sigma_aussen)
roh_aussen=radians(roh_aussen)

def BraggMatch(sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_rek):

    sig, ref =var('sig ref')

    def sigma(n_brech, sigma_aussen):
        return (asin(1/n_brech*sin(sigma_aussen)))
    def roh(n_brech, roh_aussen):
        return (asin(1/n_brech*sin(roh_aussen)))
    def gw(n_brech, sigma_aussen, roh_aussen):
        return ((sigma(n_brech, sigma_aussen)+roh(n_brech, roh_aussen))/2)
    def sigma_din(n_brech, sigma_aussen, roh_aussen):
        return (gw(n_brech, sigma_aussen, roh_aussen)-sigma(n_brech, sigma_aussen))
    def roh_din(n_brech, sigma_aussen, roh_aussen):
        return (gw(n_brech, sigma_aussen, roh_aussen)-roh(n_brech, roh_aussen))
    def p(n_brech, sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, lambda_schreib):
        return (lambda_schreib/(n_brech*(sin(sigma_din(n_brech, sigma_aussen, roh_aussen))-sin(roh_din(n_brech, sigma_aussen, roh_aussen)))))

    return (nsolve([gw(n_brech, sigma_aussen, roh_aussen)-gw(n_brech, sig, ref), p(n_brech, sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, lambda_rek)-p(n_brech, sig, ref, lambda_schreib)], [sig, ref], [0, 0]))

Winkel=BraggMatch(sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_rek)
```

I do not understand why it don´t work...

Comment: After having had from math import radians, I get an error message n_brech is undefined. After that, I get another error message var is undefined and I can't see exactly what the line involving var('gw2 ...') is supposed to do. Could you please clarify ?

Comment: The `var('gw2 ...')` function is from `sympy`, as are `nsolve()`, `asin()` and `sin()` so I've re-tagged the question with `sympy`. When I use `n_brech = 1`, I get the result as reported: `ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (0.0441366 > 2.1684e-19)`.

Comment: When I use `nsolve()` with a starting point of `[0.064,0.734]` I get the message `ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (1.44122e-06 > 2.1684e-19)`, which is much closer to the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be solved numerically, e.g. with `scipy.optimize.minimize()`:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize;
from math import radians, asin, sin;

sigma_aussen = 7.1
roh_aussen = 38
lambda_schreib = 532*10**-9
lambda_rek = 432*10**-9
sigma_aussen=radians(sigma_aussen)
roh_aussen=radians(roh_aussen)

n_brech = 1

def BraggMatch(sig,ref,sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_rek):
    sigma = asin(1/n_brech*sin(sigma_aussen))
    roh = asin(1/n_brech*sin(roh_aussen))
    gw = (sigma+roh)/2
    sigma_din =  (roh-sigma)/2
    roh_din =  (sigma-roh)/2
    gw2 = (asin(1/n_brech*sin(sig))+asin(1/n_brech*sin(ref))/2)
    sig_innen = asin(1/n_brech*sin(sig))
    ref_innen = asin(1/n_brech*sin(ref))
    sig_din = gw2-sig_innen
    ref_din = gw2-ref_innen
    p = lambda_schreib/(n_brech*(sin(sigma_din)-sin(roh_din)))
    p2 = lambda_rek/n_brech*(sin(sig_din)-sin(ref_din))
    return (gw-gw2)**2 + (p-p2)**2  

def f(x,sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_re):
    return BraggMatch(x[0],x[1],sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_re)

print(minimize(f,[0,0],args=(sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_rek)).x)
```

However I've had to guess that `n_brech = 1` because its value was not shown in the question. `scipy.optimize.minimize()` does, in fact, find a solution (`[ 0.3148574  0.1574287]`) but it is not the same solution as Maple found.

Without knowing the source of the equations and what they are intended to mean, I can't be sure that they are formulated correctly. I could, however, check for multiple solutions. Starting the optimisation at `[0.064, 0.734]` instead of at `[0, 0]` gave the result `[ 0.0340574  0.7190287]`.

Thus, it seems that there are multiple solutions for these equations and (at least for this value of `n_brech`), the optimization will find different solutions if it is started at different points.

(Further EDIT)

To investigate the multiple solutions, I used the following code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize;
from math import radians, asin, sin, log;

sigma_aussen = 7.1
roh_aussen = 38
lambda_schreib = 532*10**-9
lambda_rek = 432*10**-9
sigma_aussen=radians(sigma_aussen)
roh_aussen=radians(roh_aussen)

n_brech = 1.5

def BraggMatch(sig,ref,sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_rek):
    sigma = asin(1/n_brech*sin(sigma_aussen))
    roh = asin(1/n_brech*sin(roh_aussen))
    gw = (sigma+roh)/2
    sigma_din =  (roh-sigma)/2
    roh_din =  (sigma-roh)/2
    gw2 = (asin(1/n_brech*sin(sig))+asin(1/n_brech*sin(ref))/2)
    sig_innen = asin(1/n_brech*sin(sig))
    ref_innen = asin(1/n_brech*sin(ref))
    sig_din = gw2-sig_innen
    ref_din = gw2-ref_innen
    p = lambda_schreib/(n_brech*(sin(sigma_din)-sin(roh_din)))
    p2 = lambda_rek/n_brech*(sin(sig_din)-sin(ref_din))
    return log((gw-gw2)**2 + (p-p2)**2) 

import matplotlib
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

delta = 0.001
sig = np.arange(0, 1, delta)
ref = np.arange(0, 1, delta)
XY = [(x,y) for x in sig for y in ref]
Z = [ BraggMatch(x,y,sigma_aussen, roh_aussen, n_brech, lambda_schreib, lambda_rek) for x,y in XY]
X = [x for x,y in XY]
Y = [y for x,y in XY]
Z = np.reshape(Z,(len(sig),-1))

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(sig, ref, Z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Contour plot')
plt.xlabel('sig')
plt.ylabel('ref')

plt.show()
```

... which produces the following output:

[image]

... from which it can be seen that there are many local minima along a curve in the range of interest. Thus, I'm not surprised that different methods (and different software) find different minima.

Comment: Hallo Simon, could you read my new text. Maybe you can help me for a second time

Comment: I've added a contour plot of the solution space. I always find it is a good idea to plot the solution space when an optimisation seems to be doing something weird. In this case, it is pretty clear that there are several local minima that could be found. The question changes (I think) from "why don't different methods find the same minimum?" to "which minimum are we most interested in?". I initially plotted this graph at lower-resolution and thought there were several local minima along the curve from [0.8,0] to [0,0.4] but plotting at high res suggests there is same minimum all along the curve